# Rails, Postgres, Distinct on and ordering by another column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having some trouble with ordering using Postgres `DISTINCT ON` method. The following still orders by `unit_no` and I'm hoping to order by `site_name`.

```rb
@station = Station.select('DISTINCT ON(unit_no) unit_no, site_name, lat, long').
                   order('unit_no, site_name')
```

Comment: Do you only want order by **"site_name"**?

Comment: Yes. But with Postgres and DISTINCT ON you need to include that column in the order method.

Comment: without including that column, we can order by "site_name".

Answer (score -1):

If you want to order by only for **site_name**, than don't need to add **"unit_no"**

```
@station = Station.select('DISTINCT ON(unit_no) unit_no, site_name, lat, long').
               order('site_name')
```

Comment: This throws up an error as stated above: PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR: SELECT DISTINCT ON. You need to include the DISTINCT ON column in Postgres.

Comment: okay, there may be some other issue, as i tried in my enviornments it works, with different tables